# Convert a list of string arrays into tree structure, and also the opposite convert the tree into a list of string arrays

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a sorted array that has a list of strings arrays:

```
0:['BS', 'MS','KHB', 'CCBPO']
1:['BS', 'MS','KHB', 'HBPO']
2:['BS', 'MS','KHB', 'PBPO']
3:['BS', 'PO','BC', 'BC']
4:['H', 'I','SS', 'ESS']
5:['H', 'I','SS', 'E']
6:['H', 'D','PCD', 'D']
7:['H', 'D','P', 'HP']
ECT
```

As you can see always the first parent is located in first spot. Like in this case it's `'BS' and 'H'` and then the rest.

So for the first row we will have something like this:

```
{
          "name": "BS",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "MS",
        "children": [
            {
              "name": "KB",
        "children": [
            {
              "name": "KHB",
        "children": [
            {
              "name": "CCBPO",
              "isTrue": false
            },
              "isTrue": false
            },
              "isTrue": false
            },
              "isTrue": false
            },
        "isTrue": false

}
```

For the Second row, we will need to check if the parent is the same and add the child at the proper place which for the second row it will be in the last place and so.

After this, I want to be able to convert it into a similar structure like it was before But with a difference. For example for the first 4 rows, I will have.

```
0:['BS', 'MS','KHB', 'CCBPO']
1:['', '','', 'HBPO']
2:['', '','', 'PBPO']
3:['', 'PO','BC', 'BC']
```

Which will help me visuale the tree into a table.

Comment: none of your examples is valid javascript.

Comment: I really can't understand what you're trying to archive, please provide full examples, ideally valid javascript literals, and/or a more comprehensive description, then we might be able to help.

Comment: what tree are you talking about, what is supposed to be the parent of what,  what happend to H, I, PCD etc in your examples, where are the children array suppoed to be closed in your first example

Comment: So if you look at the answer it might be more clear.Besides that when the tree is created based on that, I need to show the data in the table view in rows. I could not find a way to do that directly. So I need to transform the data back similarly to an original array but with a difference.
If you see the last code in my question.
Then form that i need to convert back into the tree as I will save the tree structure in my json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looks like work for a recursive function. A recustive function it's a function that called itself (under a determinate circunstances)

we are going to create a function that return an array with name and children. The children are the elements of the array with the first element array is the same that the property name

createTreeAtempOne(array: any[]) {
const tree = array.reduce((a: any, b: any) => {
const el = a.find((x) => x.name == b[0]);
if (el) el.children.push(b.slice(1));
else
a.push({
name: b[0],
children: [b.slice(1)],
}
);
return a;
}, []);
}

See that if you feed this function with a simple array

```
  createTreeAtempOne(['AA'])
```

return some like

```
  {
    "name": "AA",
    "children": [
      []
    ]
  },
```

Well, we don't want this. If has no children, we want that return an object without "children" property, so change our function in the way

```
  createTreeAtempTwo(array: any[]) {
    const tree = array.reduce((a: any, b: any) => {
      const el = a.find((x) => x.name == b[0]);
      if (el){
        if (el.children)
          el.children.push(b.length > 1 ? b.slice(1) : b[0]);
        else
          el.children=[b.slice(1)]
      } else
        a.push(
          b.length > 1
          ? {
              name: b[0],
              children: [b.slice(1)],
            }
          : {name:b[0]}

        );
      return a;
    }, []);
    return tree;
  }
```

This makes that if we feed this function with

```
  createTreeAtempOne(['AA'])
```

return some like

```
  {
    "name": "AA"
  },
```

Good!! after checked with different values [['AA'],['AA','BB']], etc.. we are going to give to the function the "recursive". After get the values, we can loop over the array. If one element of the array has "children" property, call again to the function using as argument the "children"

```
  createTree(array: any[]) {
    const tree = array.reduce((a: any, b: any) => {
      const el = a.find((x) => x.name == b[0]);
      if (el){
        if (el.children)
          el.children.push(b.length > 1 ? b.slice(1) : b[0]);
        else
          el.children=[b.slice(1)]
      }
      else
        a.push(
          b.length > 1
            ? {
                name: b[0],
                children: [b.slice(1)],
              }
            : {name:b[0]}
        );
      return a;
    }, []);
    tree.forEach((t) => {
      if (t.children) t.children = this.createTree(t.children);
    });
    return tree;
  }
```

Then we need checked againts different values to see if work

In the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c9ofhr?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-flat-overview-example.ts) I use a mat-tree to show the data, but we can simply use a

```
<pre>
{{tree|json}}
</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried and it works.
I just have one extra attribute called is true;
When I create the tree This attribute will be false for all the trees.
2-I need to convert the tree into fitting table rows. The number of rows will depend on the last child. For example look at the last code provided in my question.

3-I need to convert this structure back to tree but this time the true properties will get the values from the table structure.

If you can provide this I will accept the answer cause that is exactly why I need it.
Thank you so much.